# General strategy for updating a full text search index

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search

I am using a SQL Server 2008 R2 DB with FTS enabled on it. I applied an FTS index on a table. The table is frequently updated (I mean the CUD operations). Keeping this in mind, I came up with a strategy for updating the above index:

1. I run an update population of the index when any delete occurs on that table
2. I run an update population of the index once an hour to track the newly inserted texts

I would be grateful for any constructive criticism of my ideas. Should any additional details be necessary, I will provide them.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reasoning for not using [Change Tracking-Based Population](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142575.aspx) and letting SQL Server take care of the updates automagically?

Unless you are depending on `WRITETEXT` or `UPDATETEXT` to change LOB columns (which are not tracked), I'd suggest accepting the slight overhead associated with change tracking, enable automatic population (which is the default) and rest easy.